# Leaving a pool covered for a season and through another winter

Tags: water, staining, pool, winterizing

So over the course of the year we've been remodeling the house and left the pool covered for the season. With winter approaching I'm curious to know if I should pump out all of the now green water remaining in the pool and replace it to the normal winter fill height with fresh water, or if I can just leave it until next year when we re-open the pool.

My primary concern is that the green untreated water will possibly permanently stain the liner of the pool. It's a 10k+ gallon pool and I wouldn't want to open it next season with an ugly green stain stuck at the level the water sat at all season this year.

Is that a valid fear? Or will it be fine remaining covered through the winter with the current water and opened next season without trouble?

Comment: I've never seen a swimming pool that benefited from less attention. I've seen a few that have clearly not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no permanent cosmetic damage unless you have something seriously wrong with your liner (in which case the damage is already done).

**Replacing water is very rarely the solution for algae.  In practice you can just leave it until next season.**  Of course make sure it's winterized — i.e., if you're in a freeze zone ensure all lines, pumps, and filters are clear of water; and pump the water level back down.

If it were me I'd probably also dump in a "winterizing" dose of KemTek 60% algaecide, and if you have any metal in your water or pool also a winterizing dose of stain preventer.

But there's nothing you can do to have clear water when you open it in the spring: It will have to be started up, vacuumed, balanced, etc.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like pretty solid advice, this is our first house with a pool so still learning as we go. Cheers!